# How can I add more than one column on DataGridView using string array?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and I want to fill it with two different arrays. With my current code, I can only add one column to the `DataGridView`. If I try to add two arrays only the last one is displayed on the `DataGridView`.

```
DataTable info= new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter db = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            db.Fill(info);
            if (info.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string prods= info.Rows[0]["prods"].ToString();
                string prices= info.Rows[0]["prices"].ToString();
                string[] f1 = prods.Split(',');
                string[] f2 = prices.Split(',');


                dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                dataGridView2.DataSource = f1.Select(x => new { prods= x }).ToList();
                dataGridView2.DataSource = f2.Select(y => new { prices= z }).ToList();                    
            }
```

Comment: Why not use the datatable as a datasource?  If it contains columns you dont want, change the sql select statement.  As a bonus your prices wont be down cast to string

Comment: well yes i can use the datatable as datasource but the fields that i want to use contain separated by coma string and i want those values to be displayed each on a diferent row thats why im using the strings to create 2 new columns

Comment: “the fields that i want to use contain separated by coma string”? That's a bad mistake, you need to fix that in your database before messing around in your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

So why not just add the products as the datasource and then add a column for price which you can then populate:

```
dataGridView2.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Prices", typeof(string)));

int i = 0; 

foreach (string row in prods){

    dataGridView2["Prices][i] = row;
    i++;
}
```